# A non-recursive tuple_element<index, Tuple> implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

This is basically a non-recursive `std::tuple_element` implementation.

**Note**

To make this non-recursive, you must replace `std::make_index_sequence` with a non-recursive implementation. I left it with `std::make_index_sequence` in order to reduce the amount of unrelated code.

**How it works**

`deduct` has a specialization of `deduct_impl` that is generated from the index sequence template argument it receives. It is used in order to deduce the type at index in a variadic type template or tuple. It uses the `itp_base` and `itp` types.

`itp<std::size_t>` and `itp<std::size_t, T>` is an index-type-pair used to expand the variadic indices template with a type variadic template in order to match the generated specialization.

`deducer` puts it all together by specializing `deduct` and `deduct_impl` by using `std::conditional_t` to generate the correct specialization.

Basically, for `std::tuple<void, int, char>`, in order to get the type at index 1, it creates `itp_base<0>, itp<1, int>, itp_base<2>` and passes it to `deduct` and `deduct_impl`.

#### Source code

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template <std::size_t index>
struct itp_base {};

template <std::size_t index, typename T>
struct itp : itp_base<index> {};

template <std::size_t index, typename IndexSequence>
struct deduct;

template <std::size_t index, std::size_t... indices>
struct deduct<index, std::index_sequence<indices...>>
{
    template <typename Tuple>
    struct deduct_impl;

    template <typename T, typename... R>
    struct deduct_impl<std::tuple<itp_base<indices>..., itp<index, T>, R...>>
    {
        using type = T;
    };
};

template <std::size_t index, typename... Types>
class deducer
{
private:
    static_assert( index < sizeof...( Types ), "deducer::index out of bounds" );

    template <typename IndexSequence>
    struct deducer_impl;

    template <std::size_t... indices>
    struct deducer_impl<std::index_sequence<indices...>>
    {
        using type = typename deduct<index, std::make_index_sequence<index>
        >::template deduct_impl
        <
            std::tuple
            <
                std::conditional_t
                <
                    std::is_base_of<itp_base<indices>, itp<index, Types>>::value,
                    itp<index, Types>,
                    itp_base<indices>
                >...
            >
        >::type;
    };

public:
    using type = typename deducer_impl<
        std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...( Types )>>::type;
};
```

#### Convenience aliases

```
template <std::size_t index, typename Tuple>
struct tuple_element;

template <std::size_t index, typename... Types>
struct tuple_element<index, std::tuple<Types...>> : deducer<index, Types...> {};

template <std::size_t index, typename... Types>
using tuple_element_t = typename tuple_element<index, Types...>::type;
```

#### Test case

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using tuple_t = std::tuple<int, void, std::string>;
    static_assert( std::is_same<tuple_element_t<2, tuple_t>, std::string>::value, "!" );
}
```

#### Demo

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16805356d2578d6d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach on finding the `n`th element relies on being able to construct a `tuple` with the first `n-1` types being some predictable thing that you can match against. But the types you chose for `std::tuple<void, int, char>` were, for index 1, `std::tuple<itp_base<0>, itp<1, int>, itp_base<2>>`.

But we don't actually need to introduce this `itp` thing to do this, we can simply turn it into `std::tuple<void, int, void>`. That way, `deduct_impl`'s specialization instead of taking a `std::tuple<itp_base<indices>..., itp<index, T>, R...>`, we can simplify to:

```
template <std::size_t>
using make_void = void;

template <typename T, typename... R>
struct deduct_impl<std::tuple<make_void<indices>..., T, R...>>
{
    using type = T;
};
```

And on the other side, we pass in:

```
std::tuple<std::conditional_t<(indices == index), Types, void>...>
```

Same idea, just more direct.

For that matter, we don't even need the `tuple`! `std::tuple` is an expensive type to construct at compile-time, so it's best to avoid it entirely. Just pass in the types as a pack (though the following doesn't compile on gcc - though even there you don't need `tuple`, just use a light wrapper like `template <class...> struct typelist;`)

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct deduct_impl;

template <std::size_t>
using make_void = void;

template <typename T, typename... R>
struct deduct_impl<make_void<indices>..., T, R...>
{
    using type = T;
};
```

and:

```
using type = typename deduct<index, std::make_index_sequence<index>
>::template deduct_impl
<
    std::conditional_t<(indices == index), Types, void>...
>::type;
```

**A different approach**

Another non-recursive way to do this would be through an [inheritance tree](http://talesofcpp.fusionfenix.com/post-22/true-story-efficient-packing). We basically take `std::tuple<void, int, char>` and turn it into a type that inherits from `indexed<0, void>`, `indexed<1, int>`, and `indexed<2, char>`:

```
template <std::size_t I, typename T>
struct indexed {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename Is, typename ...Ts>
struct indexer;

template <std::size_t ...Is, typename ...Ts>
struct indexer<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...>
: indexed<Is, Ts>...
{};
```

Then, given a function template constrained on an index, we can pull out the correct type:

```
template <std::size_t I, typename ...Ts>
struct at_index {
private:
    template <typename T>
    static indexed<I, T> select(indexed<I, T>);

    using impl = indexer<std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>, Ts...>;
public:
    using type = typename decltype(select(impl{}))::type;
};
```

I don't know which solution is better, but this one is certainly shorter.

Comment: The `conditional_t` condition can be simplified to `indices == index` as you point out. However, VC++ v140 generates an error saying that `index` is not in static storage. That was a workaround. I appreciate your review. If you're interested, this link was shared by dyp in the SO question I asked about this code: http://ldionne.com/2015/11/29/efficient-parameter-pack-indexing/